# How to specify another value instead of id in the Model class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[image]

How can I take the room number itself instead of going to room_num?
But so that at the same time the choice of the room remains as below
How can I implement this?

```
views.py
```

```
class RegList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Registrations.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegistrationSer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, ]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, ]
    filterset_fields = ['room_relevant']
```

```
models.py
```

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    objects = None
    room = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Комната', unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория', related_name='wer')
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Статус', default=True)
    price = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Цена', null=True,blank=True)

class Registrations(models.Model):
    objects = None
    room_num = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Номер', related_name='ertgdb',
                                 limit_choices_to={'room_bool': True})
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    tel_num = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    img = models.FileField(verbose_name='Паспорт', null=True, blank=True)
    visit_date = models.DateField(default=now, verbose_name='Дата прибытия')
    leave_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Дата отбытия')
    guest_count = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='Кол-во людей')
    room_relevant = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Статус')
    price = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Цена', default=100)
```

There are 2 models and they are interconnected
and when I connect ForeignKey Rooms in Regitrations, instead of the room number, the id comes out how to make it show the number in the GET REQUEST

```
serializers.py
```

```
class RegistrationSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Registrations
        fields = ('id', 'room_num', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'tel_num', 'img',
                  'visit_date', 'guest_count', 'room_relevant')
```

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "room_num": 1,
        "first_name": "Tangribergenov",
        "last_name": "Zafarovich",
        "tel_num": 8930005378,
        "img": null,
        "visit_date": "2023-02-16",
        "guest_count": 1,
        "room_relevant": true
    }
]
```

And I need

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "room_num": 101,
        "first_name": "Tangribergenov",
        "last_name": "Zafarovich",
        "tel_num": 8930005378,
        "img": null,
        "visit_date": "2023-02-16",
        "guest_count": 1,
        "room_relevant": true
    }
]
```

changed room_num 1 After 101

Comment: 1) Post your view and model. 2) Why is 101 the correct answer, rather than 1? I don't understand the logic.

Comment: what is the Room's __str__ method?

Comment: @NickODell 1 this is the id from the ForeignKey and 101 is the room number

Comment: Okay, so room_num is a ForeignKey, and 101 is an attribute on the object it points to? What's the name of that attribute?

Comment: @NickODellI have updated my question by adding model and views

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this using [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source):

```
class RegistrationSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_num = serializers.IntegerField(source='room_num.room')

    class Meta:
        model = Registrations
        fields = ('id', 'room_num', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'tel_num', 'img',
                  'visit_date', 'guest_count', 'room_relevant')
```

Just an FYI, Model names should be singular, you can define what would be the plural name in the `Meta` class. More information on that can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style).

For using `source` for a method can be like this:

```
#model
class Registrations(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def room_number(self):
        # logic here
        return room_num

# serailizer
room_num = serializers.IntegerField(source='room_number')
```

Another approach is using `SerializerMethodField`, like this:

```
class RegistrationSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_num = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Registrations
        fields = ('id', 'room_num', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'tel_num', 'img',
                  'visit_date', 'guest_count', 'room_relevant')
    def get_room_num(self, obj):
        # logic here
        return room_number
```

Comment: but in this case, I lose the choice of available numbers, can it be added somehow?

Comment: you can provide a default number or a method (as mentioned in the documentation of source)

Comment: no, there is not one number but 26
I can't make them by default

Comment: I have added some examples in the answer. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The DRF docs have [an example of how to do this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields):

```py
class RoomNumberField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.room


class RegistrationSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_num = RoomNumberField()

    class Meta:
        model = Registrations
        fields = ('id', 'room_num', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'tel_num', 'img',
                  'visit_date', 'guest_count', 'room_relevant')
```